# How to create a "materialized something" that accesses different tables, depending on a specific setting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

I want a program to access a table/view/stored procedure, etc. (**something materialized, let's call it X**)  that abstracts the real location of the data contained in three basic tables (the tables have the same definition in all locations).

I would want **X** to fetch the server name, catalog name and table name from somewhere (a table, probably) and access the specific three basic tables. The caller of **X** would not know which specific tables were being called.

How can I do this in SQL Server (2008)?

Comment: create view view_name as select * .... So you can query by select * from view_name.

Comment: Why don't you try with a stored procedure?

Comment: @Prasanna: what would be the advantage of a stored procedure? I only want to read data.

Comment: You can easily select depending on conditions by using a parameter

Comment: Can you explain the point of having one view in different databases that actually mean different things depending on context? And does a reference to the view in database A *always* refer to the same specific table, or is there other context involved aside from the location?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: I only want one view that will be accessed by a program. The data the view refers is the one that changes. I have different DB catalogues and I want the view to feed on a certain a catalogue. The tables are exactly the same across catalogues, the data inside them is the only things that varies.

Comment: If you only have *one* view, how does the view know which data you meant to refer to? You can't parameterize a view. I think you need to step back and explain your business requirements better, because if you've already decided this is the way you need to solve it, I believe you're going down the wrong path.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I was thinking of a table where, programatically, I would mark one of the various possible server.catalog.table combinations as active and then access the active table via a query.

Comment: If your program can instruct SQL Server to update some table to say "hey, this is what I want this view to mean right now" why can't it just say "hey, this is the data I'm after right now"? Also, if two different users are using your program at the same time, what do you expect to happen? Will one user's requirements override the others?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: The program can't say which view/table it wants. It will always use the same view. That's why I was thinking of a view that would fetch results from a table determined at run-time. What I can programatically do is set the active server.catalog.table (assuming this combination was in another table)

Comment: @John still don't know how two instances of your program would not run over each other. And what you want is not possible in a view, as I've said several times. A view can't go grab metadata from somewhere to determine where to run. So again, please define your business requirements better, instead of telling us you want a view that can dynamically determine its source table at runtime.

Comment: @AaronBertrand "A view can't go grab metadata from somewhere to determine where to run" -> this is my answer... If I used a stored procedure. Would that be possible? Thx.

Comment: @John yes, but please change your question. Right now you're asking "I want to use a tricycle to get to work, what is the best route?" when you should be asking simply, "What is the best way for me to get to work?"

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I've edited my question. The users problem you're referring isn't really a problem because this change will be done sporadically. Something like, if a new VM is lifted, the active table is changed. And besides there will be very few users. Your edited answer seems to be what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a function, a view can't use dynamic SQL - it can't go find some metadata reference somewhere and adjust accordingly.

I think the closest thing to what you want is a [synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx). Let's say you have three different databases, `A`, `B` and `C`. In `A` the table you want the view to reference is `dbo.foo`, in `B` it is `dbo.bar`, and in `C`it is `dbo.splunge`. So then you could create a synonym like so in each database:

```
USE A;
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.YourCommonViewName FOR dbo.foo;
GO

USE B;
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.YourCommonViewName FOR dbo.bar;
GO

USE C;
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.YourCommonViewName FOR dbo.splunge;
GO
```

Now this technically isn't a view, but in each database you can say...

```
SELECT <cols> FROM dbo.YourCommonViewName;
```

...and it will return the data from the database-specific table.

---

To do this in a stored procedure would be much simpler. Say you store the server, database and table name in some table, e.g. `dbo.lookup`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.lookup
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  [server]   SYSNAME,
  [database] SYSNAME,
  [table]    SYSNAME,
  active BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
);

-- you may want a constraint or trigger to ensure
-- only one row can be active at any one time.

INSERT dbo.lookup(id, [server], [database], [table])
  SELECT 1,N'serverA',N'databaseA',N'tableA'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,N'serverB',N'databaseB',N'tableB';
```

Now your program can say:

```
UPDATE dbo.lookup SET active = 1 WHERE ... ?
```

And your stored procedure can be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SELECT @sql = N'SELECT <cols> FROM ' + QUOTENAME([server]) 
    + '.' + QUOTENAME([database]) + '.dbo.' + QUOTENAME([table])
    FROM dbo.lookup WHERE active = 1;

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

I still don't understand the point, and I don't know what you're planning to do when two different users expect to call your program at the same time, and they each should get results from a different location.

Comment: Really? No dynamic SQL in table valued functions? I wasn't aware of that limitation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you can use `CASE` and variables so I suppose you could do it dynamically, but you can't use EXEC() or EXEC sp_executesql. Still, I'm not clear if we've even interpreted the actual business requirements correctly - if the aim is to do this with a single view, he's out of luck.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't ask because of the initial question but more because I couldn't believe that SQL Server has such a limitation (I'm more used to Oracle and PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Aaron on the fact that views and functions cannot use dynamic sql.

Still what you can do is build a clr table valued function. In that you can play with .net code and query whatever you want. And build you data accordingly and output what you need.

So instead of querying the data like

```
select * from myview
```

you can query it

```
select * from dbo.clr_mymockupview()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create SYNONYMs to your remote servers.
2. Create your VIEW to concatenate your locations together using UNION ALL.

Since you said "tables", join your tables before the UNION ALL and hopefully, MS will perform the JOIN remotely.

Comment: Doing a join with all locations is not an option. Too much of an overhead. I would like to fetch only the values of a certain location.

Comment: Never had the pleasure on connecting multiple MS SQL Server, but Oracle is smart enough to run queries remotely, when beneficial. That's why I said "hopefully".

Answer (score 1):

Use a union query with parameters for database, server, and catalog:

```
Select col1, col2, <etc.>, 'table1' as tablename, 'server1' as servername, 'catalog1' as catname from server1.catalog1.table1
Union Select col1, col2, <etc.>, 'table2' as tablename, 'server2' as servername, 'catalog2' as catname from server2.catalog2.table2
Union Select col1, col2, <etc.>, 'table3' as tablename, 'server3' as servername, 'catalog3' as catname from server3.catalog3.table3
```

Then filter based on your 3 criteria. This probably won't be blazing fast but will wonk with std. SQL.

Comment: Doing a join with all locations is not an option. Too much of an overhead. I would like to fetch only the values of a certain location.